# Running a document from the current subfile in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I have a problem in Texmaker. I have divided a document into a number of subfiles. I would like to compile the whole document from the current subfile without running the master file. I tried to define the current file as a master file by changing the status of the current subfile to a master file in *Options* menu. However, I receive errors after running the subfile.

Can you please give me some pieces of advice in this respect?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56107/31788

Answer (score 8):

Simply make your master file as ***Master Document***. Simply click

```
Options > Define Current Document as 'Master Document'
```

when you are in your master file. Compiling in your subfile should work.

Comment: How can you make this permanent. I mean, everytime that I open texmaker I don't want to go and click 'Define Current Document as Master Document'

I know that one way is to save everything as a session but I don't like to much this. Is there another way? Thanks.