# How to compile from a subchapter or how to set root file?

Tags: texstudio, subfiles, root

I have a document structure with subfiles/subchapters. Until now, I worked with TexMaker and TexLive on Windows and with the following line in every subfile, everything just worked great.

```
%!TEX root = ../main.tex
```

Friends recommended TexStudio as a better editor, so I tried it, but I can't compile from subfiles.
What is the problem?

Comment: Go to the master file, go to options -> current file as master, done :-)

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B. I allready found the solution, just posted this question to answer it by myself so that someone else doesn't have to search for so long as is did.

Comment: is `%!TEX root = ../main.tex` a Texmaker's feature? I think you mean texworks?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please use the form `% !TeX root = ../main.tex`

For details see the [TeXstudio user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM).

**Background information on `% !TeX`**

These 'magic' comments were first introduced by TeXShop. Afterwards, other editors started to adopt them, including TeXworks, Texmaker and TeXstudio. There's no official standard. So capabilities, and tolerance towards capitalization and spaces may be different among the editors. The above form is the original one and should be accepted by all editors.

**Additional hint**

TeXstudio has an integrated root detection. If you have main.tex open and sub.tex included in main. It automatically detects that main.tex is the root document and thus compiles that even if the editor has focus on sub.tex.

It's still good practice to set `% !TeX root` because then everything works even without an open root document. Additionally, your TeX files are more portable since AFAIK other editors do not support automatic root detection.

For further details see the [user manual section on multi file documents](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION31).

Comment: is %!TEX root = ../main.tex a Texmaker's feature? I can't find it any were!

Comment: @Tim Hoffman thank you for your reply. I got it to work. It seems TeXstudio has a bug. If you run subfiles without ever run the mainfile it's impossible to run subfiles. Since i only opened the mainfile, run it and then run a subfile everything works just fine. I found this problem with the solution in your bug tracker but it was closed. http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/474/

Comment: @besnep: That request was closed it worked for us and there was no additional feedback. You may file a new [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/). Please make sure to [describe the issue as precise as possible](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Reporting%20Bugs/).

Comment: @TimHoffmann: In my own document i couldn't reproduce this problem again. But with the original template this is reproduceable: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1629/

Answer (score 11):

*I was looking for an answer for quite some time but couldn't find an answer on the internet. Because of that i thought it would be good to post this problem with the solution i found:*

---

The solution for this problem is quite simple. The mentioned root command doesn't work in TexStudio but you can set a root file manually:

1. Open the you root/main file
2. TexStudio menu: options
3. Root document
4. Define Current Document as 'Master Document'

I hope this does help someone else.

---

**If there is a alternative to the "%!TEX root =..." command for TexStudio then please feel free to write an answer!**

Comment: related, may be help full http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56107/how-can-you-maintain-a-documents-master-mode-in-texmaker

Comment: Since TeXstudio became smarter in newer releases, setting the root document explicitly is usually not necessary anymore. For details see the [user manual section on multi file documents](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION31)

Comment: % !TeX root = root-filename      (from the doc suggested by @TimHoffmann).