# Changing the behavior of the typeset button in Texworks in multiple files scenarios

Tags: texworks, multiple-files

I have a project which consists of multiple `.tex` files, which I am typesetting using Texworks. Clicking the source code in *any file* while holding the Alt key shows correctly the corresponding position in the pdf and vice versa. However, clicking the typeset button only works in `main.tex` or `main.pdf` but does not work e.g. in `chapter1.tex` (does not have the header and is not a standalone `.tex` file and Texworks does not realize it needs to start building `main.tex` which includes `chapter1.tex`).

It is quite upsetting as I am mostly editing the chapters and clicking the button in the toolbar just gives me errors and then I have to go and search for `main.tex` and click it there. Is there a way to script Texworks or annotate the `.tex` files so that the typeset button works from any file?

For now I have hidden the toolbar in the chapter windows so that I dont click it by mistake but it is still not very user-friendly.

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287056/how-to-compile-from-a-subchapter-or-how-to-set-root-file/: you are I think looking for `%!TEX root =main.tex` as a 'magic comment' in each chapter file.

Comment: On that basis I've marked as a dupe: more for the answer than the question!

Comment: @JosephWright Sure.