# Compile error with split files using Curve?

Tags: curve-class

Writing a CV with Curve.

I have these rubic files *\makerubric{education}* and *\makerubric{workexp}*.

When I work with each rubic file I want to compile it (**typeset in texworks**) and for it to compile the entire CV. So I can immediately see the changes I've made to my CV.

But instead I have to save every edit and go back to the skeleton (**main.tex**) file and compile it from there to produce the entire CV.

%%% Code for *education.tex*: %%%

```
\begin{rubric}{education}

    \subrubric{Akademiskt}
\entry*[2015 -- 2017]
    Ekonom, 180 HP, Handelshögskolan 
\entry*[2015 -- 2017]
     Ekonom, 180 HP, Handelshögskolan 

\end{rubric}
```

When I run *education.tex* (**typeset in texworks**) I get this error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment rubric undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 \begin{rubric}
                   {education}
```

Skeleton file code **(main.tex)**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper]{curve}
\usepackage[nohead,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\leftheader{\textbf{DarVer}\\
\texttt{asdf@hotmail.fr}\\

\rightheader{1wife}
\photo{didier}
\title{AssistantPr}
\subtitle{Ph.D.incomputer}
\begin{document}
\makeheaders
\maketitle
\makerubric{workexp}
\makerubric{education}
\end{document}
```

Solved adding code to every rubic file

```
 % !TEX root = main.tex
```

Comment: If you want help, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. We cannot do anything with sniplets like this, then we have to guess, which is kinda bad

Comment: added the main code. other than that everything is here now

Comment: As far as I understand this is not an issue of TeX errors or of the `curve` class but rather an editor (TeXworks) issue. Basically you want to be able to compile the whole project while clicking the icon while you are editing a subfile.  I don't know if TeXworks recognizes instructions like `% !TEX root = path/to/main.tex` but you could try putting it into the dependent files.

Comment: This might be useful: [How to compile from a subchapter or how to set root file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287056/82917).

Comment: when im editing a makerubic file say education, which is a separate .tex file, i want to compile the entire CV from education.tex for it to produce the entire CV so i can see my changes immediately and not have to open the main.tex file and compile from there.

Comment: i will look at it , thank you